# aws-azure-login login error On MacBook: unknown option '--no-disable-extensions '

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, npm, amazon-eks

Please could someone guide me to fix this error

```
$ aws-azure-login --mode gui --profile eks-teamleader --no-disable-extensions  --no-verify-ssl

error: unknown option '--no-disable-extensions '

$ aws-azure-login --mode gui --profile eks-teamleader   --no-verify-ssl                       

Logging in with profile 'eks-8803-teamleader'...
Using AWS SAML endpoint https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml
Error: Could not find expected browser (chrome) locally. Run `npm install` to download the correct Chromium revision (901912).
    at ChromeLauncher.launch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/Launcher.js:88:27)
    at PuppeteerNode.launch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/Puppeteer.js:125:31)
    at Object._performLoginAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/lib/login.js:461:49)
    at async Object.loginAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/lib/login.js:324:30)
```

Furthermore, I have even tried:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer $ npm install

npm WARN deprecated standard-version@9.3.0: standard-version is deprecated. If you're a GitHub user, I recommend https://github.com/googleapis/release-please as an alternative.

> puppeteer@10.4.0 install
> node install.js

ERROR: Failed to set up Chromium r901912! Set "PUPPETEER_SKIP_DOWNLOAD" env variable to skip download.
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1538:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:952:8)
    at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:733:12) {
  code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
}
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aws-azure-login/node_modules/puppeteer
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node install.js
```

Note:

1. I have tried installing chromium manually in MacOs(MacBook Pro (2019 Intel Core)) but still same error
2. Have installed aws-azure-login using `npm install -g aws-azure-login`

Comment: What Azure service are you using? Have you created an issue here: https://github.com/DTN-Public/aws-azure-login/issues

Comment: @CSharpRocks our organization uses Azure Active Directory to provide SSO login to the AWS console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you have an invisible character after your option:

```
unknown option '--no-disable-extensions '
```

instead of:

```
unknown option '--no-disable-extensions'
```

try to rewrite your command because this option actually exists :)